# AWS reverse engineer Cloud formation stack from existing VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, terraform, amazon-vpc

I have an existing VPC with a few EC2 instances already created and running with security groups, route tables, NACLs all applied where required. Is there a way to convert a setup like this into a cloudformation stack or a terraform equivalent of configuration files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** A modern substitute for CloudFormer is [Former2](https://former2.com/).

---

You can use **CloudFormer**, but it doesn't seem to be maintained much anymore.

See: [Using CloudFormer (Beta) to Create AWS CloudFormation Templates from Existing AWS Resources - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html)

While that type of capability might sound like a good idea, it is quite difficult to make a template from running infrastructure. It runs into questions, such as:

- Should the definition for an Amazon EC2 instance reference the specific Security Group that currently exists, or should it create another one and reference that new one?
- Should it create a new VPC, or launch resources in the existing VPC?
- Was an instance created directly, or was it launched by Auto Scaling?

In the end, it's probably easier to just write the CloudFormation template yourself, rather than spend time trying to 'fix' one that is automatically generated.

Some **tips** for writing CloudFormation templates:

- Never write them by hand. Always copy the templates or examples from the documentation.
- Copy snippets from your existing templates rather than doing them all from scratch again.
- Use YAML rather than JSON (less errors due to unbalanced braces)

Comment: There is also TerraCognita https://github.com/cycloidio/terracognita/